# What is the difference in the quantity when graph axis shows d/10^6m and 10^6/m?

Tags: graphing-functions

What is the difference in the quantity, when deduced from a graph, when the graph axis is labelled like "$10^6/m$" and "$d/10^6m$"?

For example, for the number $5$ on the graph, would the quantity be $5*10^6$ in the first or the second "type" of labelling?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does $m$ mean something like metres or miles?  If so, what is $d$?

Comment: How I understand it: the quantity $d$ is actually $5*10^6 \text{m}$, not just $5*10^6$. So $d/10^6\text{m}$, or $d$ divided by $10^6\text{m}$, is therefore $5$.

Comment: If $d$ is in the micrometre scale, then the label $10^6d/\text{m}$ may make sense. But that can also be written as $d/\text{μm}$.

Comment: @DickGrayson I don't remember where I saw the problem. It randomly struck me and bugged me.

Comment: @Henry I took d as a variable for the quantity. And $10^6$ is just an example power I took. $10^6/m$ can also be written as $d*10^6/m$, I suppose. m is metres.